# Python tuple list

Tags: python, list, tuples

Can You help me to convert Python list:

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (3, 'e')]
```

so that:
`(1, 'a')` is index 0

`(2, 'b'), (2, 'c')` are both index 1

`(3, 'd'), (3, 'e')` are both index 2

Simply, all tuples which element[0] is equal, have same index.

Thank You,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to the rescue!:

```
lst = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (3, 'e')]
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])  #Only necessary if your list isn't sorted already.
new_lst = [list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(lst,key=lambda x:x[0])]
```

You could use `operator.itemgetter(0)` instead of the `lambda` if you wanted...

demo:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lst = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (3, 'e')]
>>> lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
>>> new_lst = [list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(lst,key=lambda x:x[0])]
>>> new_lst
[[(1, 'a')], [(2, 'b'), (2, 'c')], [(3, 'd'), (3, 'e')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want, but this will group the items into lists according ot their first element.

```
groups = collections.defaultdict(list)
for x,y in items:
    groups[x].append(y)
```

Comment: @Jon can't believe I missed that typo. Sorry for not proofreading carefully.